# R: Shapiro test by group won't produce p-values and corrupt data frame warning

Tags: r

This question has been asked before, but the solutions posed only partially solve my problem, and I've been working on this for days now. I felt it was time to seek help, even if the topic has been addressed previously. I apologize for any inconvenience.

I have a very large data.frame in R with 6288 observations of 11 variables. I want to run a Shapiro test by group on each variable, but grouped by two different factors (Number and Treatment). A much reduced sample data set with one variable is provided for example:

```
data <- data.frame(Number=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                   Treatment=c("High","High","High","High","High","High","Low",
                               "Low","Low","Low","Low","Low","High","High","High",
                               "High","High","High","Low","Low","Low","Low","Low",
                               "Low"),
                   FW=c(746,500,498,728,626,580,1462,738,1046,568,320,578,654,664,
                        660,596,1110,834,486,548,688,776,510,788))
```

I want to run a Shapiro test on `FW` by `Number` and by `Treatmen`t, so I'd have a test for 1High, 1Low, 2High, 2Low, etc. I'd like to have data for both the *W* statistic and the P-value. The original dataset contains 16 observations per group (1High,1Low,etc.; total groups=400), and an occasional `NA`; this sample dataset contains 6 observations per group (1High, 1Low, 2High, 2Low; groups=4).

The following code was previously posted as a solution to this problem of shapiro tests by groups:

```
res<-aggregate(cbind(P.value=data$FW)~data$Number+data$Treatment,data,FUN=shapiro.test)
```

I've also experimented with a number of other ways of grouping, but nothing seems to work. The above code comes closest.

The code above using aggregate groups my data appropriately, and gives me the W statistic, but it won't give me the P value (the column header says "P.value", but this is not the P value, it's the W statistic, I've confirmed this several ways). It also gives me the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

When I did a Google search for this warning, the results suggest it is a bug in the `data.frame`, but I can't figure out how to solve it. I'm not even sure it really is a bug in this case.

Can anyone help by providing some insight into the warning message, or another way to do the Shapiro test by group?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting that error because `shapiro.test` returns a list and `aggregate` expects the result of the aggregation to be a vector or a single number.

`aggregate` sees the list, takes the first element of the list by default, and tells you why it's unhappy (in admittedly vague terms). But it still gives you the Shapiro-Wilk statistic since that's the first element of the list returned from `shapiro.test`.

You can make a slight modification to your existing code that will get you what you want without issue:

```
aggregate(formula = FW ~ Number + Treatment,
          data = data,
          FUN = function(x) {y <- shapiro.test(x); c(y$statistic, y$p.value)})

#   Number Treatment       FW.W      FW.V2
# 1      1      High 0.88995051 0.31792857
# 2      2      High 0.78604502 0.04385663
# 3      1       Low 0.93305840 0.60391888
# 4      2       Low 0.86456934 0.20540230
```

Note that the rightmost columns correspond to the statistic and p-value.

This is directly extracting the statistic and p-value from the list, thereby making the result of aggregation a single vector, which makes `aggregate` happy.

---

Another option would be to use the [`data.table` package](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table), available from CRAN.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(data)

DT[,
   .(W = shapiro.test(FW)$statistic, P.value = shapiro.test(FW)$p.value),
   by = .(Number, Treatment)]

#    Number Treatment         W    P.value
# 1:      1      High 0.8899505 0.31792857
# 2:      1       Low 0.9330584 0.60391888
# 3:      2      High 0.7860450 0.04385663
# 4:      2       Low 0.8645693 0.20540230
```

Comment: Perhaps you can better help me understand how aggregate works? Based on your script, I have the following script to do a Levene's test. I want to compare within groups defined by Number, and among High and Low Treatments.

Comment: I want to compare variances within the groups defined by Number, and among High and Low Treatments (1Highx1Low, 2Highx2Low).   'aggregate(formula=data$FW~data$Number, FUN=function(x){y<-leveneTest(data$FW~data$Treatment);toString(y)})' It almost gets me what I want. It applies the levene test among all groups (1High,1Low,2High,2Low), to each Number with the same result each time. Why doesn't aggregate apply the function leveneTest within the group I designate?

Comment: @anothernewbie: Notice that you aren't using `x` in `FUN=function(x)...`. That's why `aggregate` is just giving you the same thing for each group--it's not working on different subsets of the data.

Comment: I confess: I'm stumped. The `x` in `FUN=function(x)` is the argument, but what arguments do I have to pass to the function to ask it to apply that function only to the subset I designate using `aggregate`? I can't find a good online source for explaining arguments in user defined functions. Can you recommend one?

Comment: If you're subsetting the data when you're passing it to `aggregate`, that's the only data that the `FUN` argument will use. So you can just do `data = yourdata[<subset>, ]` right in the call to `aggregate`. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

The `dplyr` package is handy for groupwise operations:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(Number, Treatment) %>%
  summarise(statistic = shapiro.test(FW)$statistic,
            p.value = shapiro.test(FW)$p.value)

  Number Treatment statistic    p.value
1      1      High 0.8899505 0.31792857
2      1       Low 0.9330584 0.60391888
3      2      High 0.7860450 0.04385663
4      2       Low 0.8645693 0.20540230
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what %>% does? I can't find it. Perhaps it would help me understand how to apply the leveneTest with group_by. Your solution worked really well for the shapiro.test, but I can't modify it for a leveneTest. Thank you!

Comment: The `%>%` operator essentially means "then", it comes from the *magrittr* package but has been incorporated into *dplyr*.  Google "dplyr piping" to read more.  Try this for the `leveneTest` if you want your subgroups to be `Number = 1` and `Number = 2`: `data %>%
  group_by(Number) %>%
  summarise(p.value = leveneTest(y = FW, group = Treatment)[1,3])` - you don't need to specify a value for the data argument because of the piping.  You may want to read the [dplyr vignette](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html).

Comment: Those are great resources, thank you @Sam Firke! The dplyr vignette was particularly helpful. With a little consultation with their instructions, I made the leveneTest work. Can you tell me what `[1,3]` does in this specific case?

Comment: `leveneTest` returns a 2x3 data.frame. `summarise` expects a single value; since I assumed you wanted the p-value, the `[1,3]` extracts the 1st row, 3rd column value from the `leveneTest` result data.frame - which is the p-value.  That is base R syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The simple dplyr answer didn't do it for me as it did not do the shapiro test on each grouped variable, but only did it once, so here's my own solution using nesting :

```
shapiro <- data %>%
  group_by(!!sym(groupvar)) %>%
  group_nest() %>%
  mutate(shapiro = map(.data$data, ~ shapiro_test(.x, !!sym(quantvar)))) %>%
  select(-data) %>%
  unnest(cols = shapiro) %>%
  print()
```