# Shapiro.test in dplyr on multiple columns at same time

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to run a normality test (shapiro-wilk) on a dataset, and I want the statistic and the p-value for all columns simultaneously. I have read all the other pages on SO ([R: Shapiro test by group won't produce p-values and corrupt data frame warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201113/r-shapiro-test-by-group-wont-produce-p-values-and-corrupt-data-frame-warning), [Using shapiro.test on multiple columns in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239826/using-shapiro-test-on-multiple-columns-in-a-data-frame)) concerning this, but still cant figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!!

Foe eg, here is the dataset: with one character vector (NVL) and rest numeric and i want to group by NVL (NV/VL).

```
     NVL  Var1  Var2  Var3  Var 4  Var 5
1.   NV   22.5  26.8   89.2  35.7   100
2.   NV   34.7  67.4   29.8  12.4   100
3.   NV   68.3  34.5   44.5  23.8   100
4.   NV   11.2  55.3   17.5  77.9   100
5.   VL   55.6  77.2   59.7  89.6   100
6.   VL   60.5  88.7   65.4  99.6   100
7.   VL   89.4  87.5   65.9  89.5   100
8.   VL   65.4  74.2   75.4  89.5   100
9.   VL   81.8  78.5   95.4  92.5   100
```

Here is the code:

```
library(dplyr)
normalityVar1<-mydata %>%
group_by(NVL) %>%
summarise(statistic = shapiro.test(Var1)$statistic, 
p.value = shapiro.test(Var1)$p.value)
```

Here is the output:

```
NVL statistic   p.value
  <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1    VL 0.9125239 0.1985486
2    NV 0.8983501 0.2101248
```

Now, do i edit this code, so that I can get this output for all the variables (Var2, 3, 4 ,5) at the same time? I even tried aggregate and sapply, but I am stuck.

```
aggregate(formula = Var1 ~ NVL,
data = mydata,
FUN = function(x) {y <- shapiro.test(x); c(y$statistic, y$p.value)})
```

As you can see, I am able to do this for only one variable! I know i am close, but i just cant figure it out anymore!! Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mydata <- read.table(text="
   NVL  Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5
1   NV   22.5  26.8   89.2  35.7   100
2   NV   34.7  67.4   29.8  12.4   100
3   NV   68.3  34.5   44.5  23.8   50
4   NV   11.2  55.3   17.5  77.9   100
5   VL   55.6  77.2   59.7  89.6   100
6   VL   60.5  88.7   65.4  99.6   100
7   VL   89.4  87.5   65.9  89.5   100
8   VL   65.4  74.2   75.4  89.5   90
9   VL   81.8  78.5   95.4  92.5   90
", header=T)

library(dplyr)
myfun <- function(x, group) {
  data.frame(x, group) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(
    statistic = ifelse(sd(x)!=0,shapiro.test(x)$statistic,NA), 
    p.value = ifelse(sd(x)!=0,shapiro.test(x)$p.value,NA)
  )
}
(lst <- lapply(mydata[,-1], myfun, group=mydata[,1]))
```

The output is:

```
$Var1
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   group statistic   p.value
  <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     NV 0.9313476 0.6023421
2     VL 0.9149572 0.4979450

$Var2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   group statistic   p.value
  <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     NV 0.9409576 0.6601747
2     VL 0.8736587 0.2815562

$Var3
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   group statistic   p.value
  <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     NV 0.9096322 0.4804557
2     VL 0.8644349 0.2446131

$Var4
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   group statistic    p.value
  <fctr>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1     NV 0.9003135 0.43261822
2     VL 0.7260939 0.01760713

$Var5
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   group statistic     p.value
  <fctr>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1     NV 0.6297763 0.001240726
2     VL 0.6840289 0.006470001
```

The `lst` output list can be transformed into a `data.frame` object:

```
do.call(cbind, lst)[,-seq(4,3*(ncol(mydata)-1),3)]
```

Here is the output:

```
  Var1.group Var1.statistic Var1.p.value Var2.statistic Var2.p.value Var3.statistic Var3.p.value Var4.statistic Var4.p.value Var5.statistic Var5.p.value
1         NV      0.9313476    0.6023421      0.9409576    0.6601747      0.9096322    0.4804557      0.9003135   0.43261822      0.6297763  0.001240726
2         VL      0.9149572    0.4979450      0.8736587    0.2815562      0.8644349    0.2446131      0.7260939   0.01760713      0.6840289  0.006470001
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! I did this but got the error: Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: all 'x' values are identical. I don't know why I keep getting this error, even though the values are not identical. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Shades I changed some values of column `Var5` because it is constant in your dataset and the Shapiro test cannot be applied.

Comment: Okay! So is that true of any normality test - cant be applied to a constant? Also, do you have any suggestions for skipping these constant value columns - and picking specific columns of the dataset. How can i edit the code then? Sorry to bother you!

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `summarise_all`:

```
mydata <- read.table(text="
   NVL  Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5
1   NV   22.5  26.8   89.2  35.7   100
2   NV   34.7  67.4   29.8  12.4   100
3   NV   68.3  34.5   44.5  23.8   50
4   NV   11.2  55.3   17.5  77.9   100
5   VL   55.6  77.2   59.7  89.6   100
6   VL   60.5  88.7   65.4  99.6   100
7   VL   89.4  87.5   65.9  89.5   100
8   VL   65.4  74.2   75.4  89.5   90
9   VL   81.8  78.5   95.4  92.5   90
", header=T)


library(dplyr)
normalityVar1<-mydata %>%
  group_by(NVL) %>%
  summarise_all(.funs = funs(statistic = shapiro.test(.)$statistic, 
                             p.value = shapiro.test(.)$p.value))
```

With the desired output:

```
normalityVar1
# A tibble: 2 x 11
    NVL Var1_statistic Var2_statistic Var3_statistic Var4_statistic Var5_statistic Var1_p.value Var2_p.value Var3_p.value
  <fctr>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1     NV      0.9313476      0.9409576      0.9096322      0.9003135      0.6297763    0.6023421    0.6601747    0.4804557
2     VL      0.9149572      0.8736587      0.8644349      0.7260939      0.6840289    0.4979450    0.2815562    0.2446131
# ... with 2 more variables: Var4_p.value <dbl>, Var5_p.value <dbl>
```

Note that you first have all statistics and then all p-values. Reordering of the columns - if necessary - should be simple.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I used summarise_all, I had tried that earlier too, but this is the error I get: Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: all 'x' values are identical. The values are not identical except for one variable (Var5) i guess. Any suggestions would be great!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest constructing a long-format ("tidy") dataset and using the `tidiverse` functions.

Load packages:

```
library(dplyr)      # for data manipulation functions
library(tidyr)      # for data manipulation functions
library(data.table) # for function `fread`
library(broom)      # for function `tidy`
```

Read data into `R`:

```
data <- fread(
"NVL   Var1  Var2   Var3  Var4   Var5
  NV   22.5  26.8   89.2  35.7   100
  NV   34.7  67.4   29.8  12.4   100
  NV   68.3  34.5   44.5  23.8   50
  NV   11.2  55.3   17.5  77.9   100
  VL   55.6  77.2   59.7  89.6   100
  VL   60.5  88.7   65.4  99.6   100
  VL   89.4  87.5   65.9  89.5   100
  VL   65.4  74.2   75.4  89.5   90
  VL   81.8  78.5   95.4  92.5   90")
```

Do the analysis:

```
# 1. Gather the variables that values should be tested.
# 2. Group by variable with variable names (`variable_name`) and 
#    by all group variables (in our case `NVL`).
# 3. Do the test for `value` and tidy the result.
# 4. Ungroup (it's a good practice to do this). 
# 5. Remove unnecessary information (column `method`).

sw_test_results <- data %>% 
    gather(key = "variable_name", value = "value", Var1:Var5) %>% 
    group_by(variable_name, NVL)  %>% 
    do(tidy(shapiro.test(.$value))) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-method)

sw_test_results
```

The results:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   variable_name NVL   statistic p.value
   <chr>         <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Var1          NV        0.931 0.602  
 2 Var1          VL        0.915 0.498  
 3 Var2          NV        0.941 0.660  
 4 Var2          VL        0.874 0.282  
 5 Var3          NV        0.910 0.480  
 6 Var3          VL        0.864 0.245  
 7 Var4          NV        0.900 0.433  
 8 Var4          VL        0.726 0.0176 
 9 Var5          NV        0.630 0.00124
10 Var5          VL        0.684 0.00647
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the excellent answer by @GegznaV,
here's an update with the newer constructs `tidyr::pivot_longer` replacing `tidyr::gather`, and the `nest-unnest` syntax.

In my experience,  `broom::glance` is more reliable to give the statistics of a test than `broom::tidy` but you can try both.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -NVL,
    names_to = "variable_name",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>% 
  nest(data = -c(variable_name, NVL)) %>% 
  mutate(
    shapiro = map(data, ~shapiro.test(.x$value)),
    glanced = map(shapiro, glance),
    tidied = map(shapiro, tidy)
  ) %>% 
  unnest(glanced) %>% 
  select(NVL, variable_name, W = statistic, p.value)
```